# Unable to call Intent.putExtra() within my own Class

Tags: java, android

I have decorator pattern instances in an `ArrayList`.

It works well, but when I try to call `putExtra()`, it does not work -- my activity can't start.

When I comment out the statement `i.putExtra(FRIENDSARRAY, (Serializable)friends);`  it works - the activity starts. How can I add it using `putExtra()` and how can I read this from the `FriendlistTabHost` class?

```
List<IComplexListItem> friends = new ArrayList<IComplexListItem>();
JSONArray friendList = answer.getJSONArray("friendlist");

for (int i = 0; i < friendList.length(); i++) {
   ...
   FriendListItem actualFriend = new FriendListItem(i, 15, "name",41242214123);
   ComplexFriendListItem cpItem = new ComplexFriendListItem(actualFriend);
   friends.add(cpItem);
}

Intent i = new Intent();

i.putExtra(FRIENDSARRAY, (Serializable)friends);                     
i.setClass(mContext, FriendlistTabHost.class);
mContext.startActivity(i);
```

Comment: Can you post the log cat error please?

Comment: java.lang.RuntimeException: Parcel: unable to marshal value com.example.***.adapters.ComplexFriendListItem@42172a40
full here: http://pastebin.com/rvyT7EPB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I strongly recommend looking into [parcelable](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html) instead of Serializable as it's much faster on Android. So first, impement `Parcelable` in your class

Then to send your list with the intent, do the following

```
i.putParcelableArrayList("FriendsArray", friends);
```

To retrieve it in the next activity, do the following

```
ArrayList<IComplexListItem> friends = (ArrayList<IComplexListItem>) getIntent().getParcelableArrayListExtra("FriendsArray");
```

Comment: Could you post/link your entire ComplexFriendListItem class?